# Email isn't inserted into mysql database from form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a newsletter for one of my sites and I can't the email posted to the mysql database.

Here is the html form code:
    
    
        
        subscribe

```
        <h2>newsletter</h2>
        <br /><input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />

        <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="submit_it()" value="OK" />

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function submit_it() {

                var cate_value = $('#cate').val();
                var email_value = $('#email').val();

                $.post("subscribe.php", { email: email_value , cate: category_value }, function(response) {

                    if (response!='') {alert(response)};
                    alert('ok');

                });

            }

        </script>


</body>
```

And here is the php processing code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "some_user";
$password = "some_pass";
$database = "news";


$server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);


function sql_quote($value) {

    $value = str_replace('<?','',$value);
    $value = str_replace('script','',$value);

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    } else {
        if ((string)$value[0] == '0') {
            $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }}
    return $value;
}



$q = "INSERT INTO emails (email,cate) VALUES (".sql_quote($_POST['email']).",".$_POST['cate'].")";

mysql_query($q);
```

?>

Any help would be much appreciated because I've been fooling with this for the last 5hrs trying to make it work and I just can't figure it out plus I can't look at it anymore. My eyes hurt now. lol Thanks again.

Comment: Please post more details on the errors you are receiving. We need something more detailed then "Form will not input info into mysql database"

Comment: Basically what happens is when you submit the email, you get the "Thank You!" message but the email doesn't actually get inserted into the mysql database. It's not writing it to the database for some reason.

Comment: You could print out $q to see the query it is trying to run, and you could also update mysql_query($q); to mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error()); to see the error that is being generated (if one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely rewrite your code as hobodave suggests.  I think something is wrong with your db configuration, though.  Try this in the meantime, to execute your query:

```
$result = mysql_query($q);
if( $result ){
    echo( 'OK' );
} else {
    echo( 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP `sql_quote` function is *very* naive with it's str_replace() filtering. It is trivial to bypass this and insert unwanted data in your database.

I suggest the following rewrite of your code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "some_user";
$password = "some_pass";
$database = "newsletter";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

function sql_quote($value)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$email = $_POST['email'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) 
    && FALSE !== filter_var($category, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
) {
    $q = sprintf("INSERT INTO emails (email, category) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
        sql_quote($email),
        sql_quote($category)
    );
    // execute query
} else {
    // Do what you want with invalid data
}
```

I'd also suggest the following changes:

- [Disable magic_quotes_runtime](http://php.net/set_magic_quotes_runtime) so you don't need to check, thus you can do away with sql_quote entirely
- Use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)

**Edit:**

Why are you even using AJAX to process this form submission? I don't see any benefit in it. You're not doing anything special, just submitting a form.

I'd suggest removing the AJAX altogether and just using the submit button as it's intended.

If you insist though, you can at least temporarily remove it to simplify your testing.

Comment: The reason why is because some my backend is written in AJAX so just I just thought I would use it here. In my backend I use AJAX to submit emails and it works fine but for some reason I can't get it working with the ajax_subscribe.php script. I'm just going to remove the AJAX until I have time to fix it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your query try this

```
$email = sql_quote($_POST['email']);
$category = $_POST['category'];
$q = "INSERT INTO emails (email,category) VALUES ('$email','$category')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `data` as key for your data.

```
 $.ajax(url: "ajax_subscribe.php", 
         method : 'POST',
         data: { email: email_value , category: category_value },           
         success: function(response) {

                if (response!='') {alert(response)};
                alert('Thank You !');

            });
```

Comment: -1: Incorrect. You are describing the use of jQuery.ajax() _not_ jQuery.post()